# Slow navigation transitions after changing semanticContentAttribute

Tags: ios, swift, localization, arabic, right-to-left

I have an application that support two languages: Arabic & English. I'm changing UI direction inside the app after user choose language.

I use this code:

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = isRTL ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
```

This code is working well, but after changing direction my navigation transition (push or pop) becomes too slow and when I kill app and open it again all back to normal.

When I remove changing semanticContentAttribute all work fine, but I have to use this code for supporting Arabic language.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Got any updates on this issue?